# C program to create a simple calculator

Tags: c, input, scanf

I am tryings to create a simple calculator...
I am learning C program. I need to write a program to create a calculator using switch statement. When I try to run this code the program stops in the middle of it when running and I didn't know what is causing this.
Here is the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    float n1,n2,ans;
    char op,x;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter 1:");
        scanf("%f",&n1);
        printf("Enter 2:");
        scanf("%f",&n2);
        printf("Enter operator:");
        scanf("%c",&op);

        switch(op)
        {
            case'+': ans=n1+n2;break;
            case'-': ans=n1-n2;break;
            case'*': ans=n1*n2;break;
            case'/': ans=n1/n2;break;
            default:printf("Invalid operator\n");
        }

        printf("Answer= %.2f\n",ans);
        printf("Do you want to try it again?(y/n)");
        scanf("%c",&x);
    }
    while(x=='y' || x=='Y');
 }
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&op);` read a `'\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the buffer. Try this correction that I made

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
        float n1, n2, ans;
        char op,x;
        do {
            printf("Enter 1:");
            scanf("%f",&n1);
            printf("Enter 2:");
            scanf("%f",&n2);
            getchar();
            printf("Enter operator:");
            scanf("%c",&op);

            switch(op) {
                case'+': ans=n1+n2;break;
                case'-': ans=n1-n2;break;
                case'*': ans=n1*n2;break;
                case'/': ans=n1/n2;break;
                default:printf("Invalid operator\n");
            }
            printf("Answer= %.2f\n",ans);
            printf("Do you want to try it again?(y/n)");
            getchar();
            scanf("%c",&x);
            printf("%c\n",x );
        }while(x=='y' || x=='Y');
        return 0;
    }
```